# c# how to maintain created dynamic buttons at next startup

Tags: c#

i am facing a trouble for few days. I had create a dynamic buttons at runtime but it will disappear on the next startup. please help. below is my coding.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createNewTable createTable = new createNewTable();

        DialogResult dResult = createTable.ShowDialog();
        string table_name = "";

        if (dResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            table_name = createTable.tableName;
            createTable.Dispose();
        }
        else if (dResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            createTable.Dispose();
        }

        if(table_name != string.Empty){
            Button textbox = new Button();

            textbox.Name = "btn_" + table_name;
            textbox.Text = table_name;
            textbox.Height = 55;
            textbox.Width = 123;
            textbox.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(textbox_MouseDown);
            textbox.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(textbox_MouseMove);
            textbox.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(textbox_MouseUp);
            textbox.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;

            this.Controls.Add(textbox);
            }

}
```

i had searched some info like using XMLSerialize/application settings but it dont provided any sample for me how to add dynamic button using XMLSerialize. please help..

Comment: I don't think there is a possibility to serialize a button out of the box. You will have to create an object containing the data (Name, Text, etc) and serialize this. Then you could deserialize the data and create the button again at next startup.